# Can you acquaint a randomization test with any test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, resampling, permutation-test

I want to determine whether my randomizer works properly in a statistical test. One method to do this is a randomization test where we try all possible combinations for two groups. For example: could I wrap a randomization test around the Mann-Whitney U test?

```
- Method: Randomized Mann-Whitney U test
For i to N
    p_i = Mann-Whitney U Test(Random(A), Random(B) )
```

Or more generally, could I wrap the randomized test around any statistical test?

Comment: How would you do this for one sample tests?

Comment: I suppose it would not work in that case because the data points would just be shuffled. Nice find. But it still works very naturally for two-sample tests.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "acquaint" in the title. However, the Mann Whitney is already a permutation test (done on rank-transformed data). You can do this, but unless there's ties, it would add nothing.

Comment: Let's say it was student's T-test. From what I understand, I believe that this would work well.

Comment: @dsaxton Actually you *can* do one sample randomization tests, you just have to think more carefully about what, exactly, gets  permuted (you don't just shuffle data!).

Comment: zero, Could you clarify your question a bit, then? If you're asking "can I do a randomization test using a t-test statistic?" the answer is "certainly"; if you're asking a more general question, perhaps propose using both statistics as examples (with *t* first though). [I'm not sure much purpose is served by your pseudocode there.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use almost any statistic you like in a randomization test. Some will be more useful than others.

So yes, you could put in a t-statistic (but personally I'd tend to just use the difference in means, or even just the mean of the first sample as statistics).

Once you get past simple situations it may be quite hard to come up with a good statistic for which you can treat group-labels as exchangeable under the null (sometimes you may be able to add some assumptions which make it easier to find a suitable one).

[As noted in earlier comments, you could put a Mann-Whitney statistic in but unless there were ties it would add nothing, since the Mann-Whitney is already a permutation test on the ranks; you'd just be doing a noisy version of the Mann-Whitney.]

Comment: Nice! I wonder why it isn't ALWAYS used with any test (aside from computational limitations)? Would it ever mess up our results?

Comment: @zero There's already a partial answer above, but "Why don't we always use randomization tests?" wouldn't be a bad question. Check first that it or something very close hasn't already been asked (I have a feeling it probably has).